# How two create a prisma object with multiple id fields

Tags: graphql, prisma, graphql-js, prisma-graphql

After a lot of research, I unfortunately could not find a solution to my problem.

I have a prisma schema which has two fields (numberPlate - String, controlTime - DateTime) concatenated as ID.

If I expose the field controlTime also as ID I get the following error message:

```
Type error: Argument of type '"controlTime"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CompatibleTypes<ExtendDefaultTypes<{ PrismaTypes: PrismaTypes; }>, CarControl, "ID", boolean> | undefined'.
```

**schema.prisma**

```
model CarControl {
  numberPlate  String
  controlTime  DateTime
  carModel     CarModel @relation(references: [modelName], fields: [model])
  model        String
  carColor     Color    @relation(references: [colorName], fields: [color])
  color        String
  latitude     Float
  longitude    Float
  carInspector String   @db.VarChar(256)
  photoPath    String

  @@id([numberPlate, controlTime], name: "CarControl_pkey")
}
```

**CarControl.ts**

```
import { builder } from '../builder'

builder.prismaObject('CarControl', {
  fields: (t) => ({
    numberPlate: t.exposeID('numberPlate'),
    controlTime: t.exposeID('controlTime'),
    carModel: t.relation('carModel'),
    carColor: t.relation('carColor'),
    latitude: t.exposeFloat('latitude'),
    longitude: t.exposeFloat('longitude'),
    carInspector: t.exposeString('carInspector'),
    photoPath: t.exposeString('photoPath'),
  })
})

// Query to get all number plates
builder.queryField('NumberPlates', (t) =>
  t.prismaField({
    type: ['CarControl'],
    resolve: (query, _parent, _args, _ctx, _info) =>
      prisma.carControl.findMany({ ...query })
  })
)
```

Do you know what I have to do?

Thank you in advance for your help.

I have already tried many things. I hope someone can give me an idea or a good approach to solve my problem.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to include date field in the id?

Comment: I am just guessing what you are trying to do. If you want to add fields to your prisma type that are non-expose, you have to use the `select` field to define which fields your computation depends on: https://pothos-graphql.dev/docs/plugins/prisma#example Something like: `id: t.id({ select: { numberPlate: true, controlTime: true }, resolve: ... })`.